# AppModelV2: Unable to get access token for some users on Internet Explorer

Tags: node.js, passport.js, azure-active-directory, adal, passport-azure-ad

I implemented a  model for unified app authentication using `passport-azure-ad` from this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web. This is my code:

```
post('/azure/callback', (req : express.Request, res : express.Response, next : Function) => {
    if ((req.query.error || req.query.error_description) &&
        req.query.state) {
        return res.render('oAuthWindow');
    }
    passportAzureOAuth.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', (err, user, info) : any => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(422).send(err);
        } else {
            return res.render('oAuthWindow');
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

I have registered a function `azureOauthVerify` with `passport-azure-ad` as follows:

```
// Registered function with callback from azure

azureOAuthVerify(req, iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) {}

azureOAuthConfig = {
    identityMetadata : nconf.get('AZURE_END_POINT'), // For using Microsoft you should never need to change this.
    clientID : nconf.get('AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
    responseType : 'id_token code',
    responseMode : 'form_post',
    passReqToCallback : true,
    realm : constants.StringConstants.API_END_POINT,
    validateIssuer : false,
    skipUserProfile : true,
    redirectUrl : constants.StringConstants.API_END_POINT + constants.StringConstants.AZURE_CALLBACK_URL,
    clientSecret : nconf.get('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    scope : ['https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read', 'offline_access']
};
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(azureOAuthConfig, azureOAuthVerify));
```

The issue is all the users using Chrome are able to login properly, but for some users (not everybody), on Internet Explorer, who are using Office email are unable to login.

I just debugged the issue and found out that the acesss token is not received from the `AZURE_ENDPOINT`, i.e `/azure/callback` is called but the function registered with passport, `azureOauthVerify`, is not called.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide details on what these users are observing? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Users are not seeing any error.  passport.authenticate() is called but in this case azureOauthVerify is not called and the popup shown to the user is closed

Comment: can it be because of the permissions defined in the scope?

Comment: I just figured out that I am using cookieSession() in express and this particular req doesnt have Session information in it. so passport is unable to deserialize the user, but not sure why this happens only in some IE11 browsers